# Formatblock cross browser compatible alternative

Tags: safari, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7

I'm using the jhtmlarea html editor in a webb application.
Now during testing I found out that it doesn't work properly with setting headers (h1-4) since it uses the execcommand with "formatblock".

According to [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html) this isn't supported by for example IE7 and testing has shown that it also has issues in Safari 3-4.

This is at the end of the development project so I need a solution quite fast. Does anybody have any idea on how to make a crossbrowser compatible solution for setting headers?

Comment: Can you afford a change to a new editor?

Comment: I depends. I started of with nicedit but had some issues with it. What I want is a simple editor with functions like:
 bold,italic, underline, heading1-4 forecolor, backcolor, link. Ahead maybe i also want to extend it.The editor is inserted in the page by javascript on certain actions. I'll take any suggestion you have.

Comment: Added a temp fix. For IE7 and safari I use a trick lined out in http://ajaxian.com/archives/tales-of-the-rich-text-editor-and-safari-support.
Use execCommand with 'fontname' = 'mytempfont'. Then search for the created container.
var container = $([style*=mytempfont)
container.replaceWith("<h1>" + container.html() + "</h1>);.

Still intrested in a "real" solution.